# Cadastrar no banco mysql um array

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber se é possível inserir vários valores dentro de uma variável no html, passar via POST para o php e cadastrar cada um em uma linha no banco.

Por exemplo, cadastrar vários nomes através do campo name= "nome".

juntar tudo, manda pro php e inserir um em cada linha.
Precisaria um forma que eu possa acrescentar mais coisas e ele não mistura-se. Se eu quisesse acrescentar sobrenome, idade e sexo, e na hora de cadastrar cadastrar toda uma linha para depois ir para outra.

```
<html>
<form action = "cadastro/cadastrando.php" method="POST">

  <tr>

    <td>Nome:
    <label for="nome"></label></td>
    <td height="33"><input type="text" name="nome"  size="30" required/></td>
    <td width="267">

        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nome 2:
    <label for="nome"></label></td>
    <td height="33"><input type="text" name="nome"  size="30" required/></td>
    <td width="267">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <td>Nome:
    <label for="nome"></label></td>
    <td height="33"><input type="text" name="nome"  size="30" required/></td>
    <td width="267">
    </td>

     <br>
     <br>

    <center><button type="submit"  >Cadastrar <span class=""></span></button></center>

    <br>
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da sim, primeiro voce precisa usar o html assim

```
<input type="text" name="nome[]"  size="30" required/>
```

Depois voce pode usar um `for` ou `foreach` para percorrer o array

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['nome']); $i++){
   $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tabela SET nome = ?");
   $sql->execute($_POST['nome'][$i]);
}
```

Comment: Cara nem sabia que isso existia, por curiosidade como é identificado o inicio e o fim de um nome no input?